# Given $C$ a field, $f$ a polynomial in $C[x]$ and $I = (f)$, describe $C[x]/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

In my course it has been proven that the set $I_f$ whose elements are of the form $r+I$ ,where $r\in C[x]$ such that $r=0$ or $\deg(r) < \deg(f)$, is in bijection with $C[x]/I$.

I wonder whether it is possible to state a stronger fact: $I_f = C[x]/I$.

It may follow from the fact that $C[x]/I$ is an Euclidean Domain; if $g\in C[x]/I$ then there exist $h,r\in C[x]/I$ such that $g=fh+r$ and $r=0$ or $\deg(r)<\deg(f)$, implying that $g+I=fh+r+I=r+I$.

Is this observation sufficient to state that any class in $C[x]/I$ has at least one representative and thus to prove that $C[x]/I = I_f$?

In addition, if the field is finite and $n=|C|$ is it true that $|I_f|=n^{\deg(f)}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)\in \Bbb C[x]$ and $I=(f(x))$.

> Consider $\psi: \Bbb C[x]\to \frac{\displaystyle \Bbb C[x]}{\displaystyle I}$, defined by $\psi(g(x))=g(x)+I$.

Here $\psi$ is a surjection.

Comment: Using your notation: if $g=fh+r$ and $r=0$ or $\deg(r)<\deg(f)$, the bijection I'm talking about is given by $\phi(g+I)=r+I$

Comment: The map $\psi $ sends an element in $\Bbb C[x]$ to a class. Also here $r+I=g+I$. The point here is that every element in $\Bbb C[x]/I$ is a member of some class and hence is bound to have a perimage by the definition of $\psi$

Comment: Your bijection is the same as mine. You choose a different representative for the class that's it. Both the maps are one and the same.

Comment: The domain is different: $\phi$ goes from $C[x]/I$ to $\psi(I_f)$, am I correct?

Comment: I'm a little confused here, can you define your map explicitly?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The bijection is $\psi:C[x]/I$ --> $I_f$ given by  $\psi(g+I)=r+I. The set I_f is as described before.